# AutoMapper Master details mapping

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

We are using AutoMapper for mapping business entities to data entities and vice versa. There are two classes, on which we would like to do updates on database.

**ImportConfiguration**

```
[DataContract]
public class ImportConfiguration : FileType
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid ImportConfigurationID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string FileMask { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual List<OrderConfiguration> OrderConfigurations { get; set; }
}
```

**OrderConfiguration**

```
[DataContract]
public class OrderConfiguration 
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid OrderConfigurationID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Guid ImportConfigurationID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string OrderConfigData{ get; set; }
}
```

Here is the mapping from Business entity to data entity for ImportConfiguration.

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<ImportConfiguration, Data.Entities.ImportConfigurations>()
              .ForMember(d => d.OrderConfigurations, o => o.UseDestinationValue());
```

But when we are creating the mapping by

```
var newDbconfig = Mapper.Map<ImportConfiguration, Data.Entities.ImportConfigurations>(newBoConfig);
```

Following error message is raised :

**Error Message :**

The EntityCollection has already been initialized. The InitializeRelatedCollection method should only be called to initialize a new EntityCollection during deserialization of an object graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core problem comes from the fact that you should not set an `EntityCollection`, which is what happens in the mapping. The collection is managed by its holder and you only should be adding objects to it.

Since you want to basically ignore the destination value (keeping the destination value), just use the `Ignore()` method on the options for the `ImportConfigurations`

Custom behavior can be added using the `AfterMap` method if you need to act on the `EntityCollection`